# Performance on BIRT for 125k record data set

Tags: performance, report, birt

I've got a data set consisting of 125,000 records which takes about 2 minutes to load when I run the query in SQL developer.

In BIRT I create a data source and data set and just drag the data set onto the canvas. I don't add any formatting or grouping or anything like that.

When it comes to running the report on Chrome the whole thing takes about 40 minutes and I would like to know a way to make this more efficient or if anyone can shed some light on why this takes so long!

I have a very high spec machine, with 16GB ram and an i7 processor, so hardware isn't the issue I don't think

thanks in advance

Comment: Is your raw data set 125K or is your result set 125K? How many columns, and are you creating as HTML, Excel, or what?

Comment: You should also check if generating the report or rendering the resulting HTML (I assume you are generating HTML output) takes so long. Browsers are extremely slow when you feed them with a HTML table with several thousands rows.

Comment: Furthermore, how long does it take with SQL*Developer to scroll down to the last record (by default SQL*Developer only shows the first 50 rows)? And consider tuning the rowFetchSize query property to a reasonable value. For example, set it to 500 to always fetch 500 rows in one block from the DB. Depending on network speed and latency, this might make a difference.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - the raw data is 125k and so is the data set, no manipulation of the data or anything is done. Creating as HTML with 15 columns worth of data

Comment: @hvb - How do I check which part of the process is the bit that takes time? It took 2 minutes to scroll to the bottom of the 125k data set. network speed or any other factors like that aren't the issue

Thanks all!

Comment: In my experience Chrome is much better at handling difficult reports than Firefox or IE.  If you trying opening with either of those and they crash you are at the top limit of converting to HTML. Also try running the report to Excel, I have dumped some big data sets in to Excel in 5 minutes or less with BIRT (had to use chrome though)

Comment: @Dan if you need to process such large result sets you should  increase significantly the heap memory of java, it is probably set to only 512 Mb in your Eclipse Designer. Though 125K  records would result in a report with about 3500 pages, does it really make sense? Why not filtering with query parameters and aggregating in SQL?

Comment: @JamesJenkins - it is about 3x as quick when doing it straight to PDF, which I guess could work! I'll try doing it straight to XLS and see how long that takes

Comment: @Dominique - Max heap size is set to 4GB! Doesn't make much sense to me either but the customer is always right ey ;)

Comment: Well, when scrolling down in SQL developer can be some in 2 minutes, then SQL performance is not the cause.

Comment: Are you using separate RunTask and RenderTask? That is slooow for big results. Try using RunAndRenderTask instead.

Comment: I made a test with 158K records from MySQL, 7 columns and a medium config (i5 processor 1.5 GB heap memory): it generates a PDF of 5200 pages in about 35 seconds. In your case is there a column with a particular type such a long text, a blob, an image, an XML format  or something like that? Try to run the report with just a few columns first, it might help to highlight the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to resolve this issue was to schedule the report to run as a PDF which takes about 5 minutes in total